# Clarification on definition of function being defined in a punctured neighbourhood of a point

Tags: calculus

The textbook I'm reading says that a function $f$ being defined in a punctured neighbourhood of a point $x$ means that the function is defined over an interval which has $x$ as an inner point, but isn't defined at $x$ itself. Later on, in the section of extremal points of functions, the following is said about singular points:

...a singular point is a point at which the function (at least) is defined in a punctured neighbourhood of it, but either $f$ or $f'$ is not continuous or not defined at the point.

I'm having trouble understanding this bit. According to the definition of $f$ being defined in a punctured neighbourhood of a given point, doesn't that imply that it isn't defined there?

Comment: The definition of "defined on a punctured neighborhood of $x$" you gave seems poor. I believe it should say that $f$ is not *necessarily* defined at $x$ itself, but could be.

Comment: Please identify the textbook.

Comment: The emphasis is on 'at least'. Even the case where $f$ is defined everywhere is considered.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks!